# Find the x-coordinate of each point where the tangent line of $2y(3 − x) = x^4$ is vertical.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

Question: Find the $x$-coordinate of each point where the tangent line of $2y(3−x)=x^4$ is vertical.

My work so far: Using implicit differentiation, we get that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x^3 +y}{3-x}.$
Therefore, the derivative is undefined when $3 - x = 0,$ making $x = 3.$

Are there any other solutions to the problem?

Comment: There is no such point within $\operatorname{dom}(f)$, with $y=f(x)=\frac{x^4}{2(x-3)}$.

Comment: @K.defaoite I think your argument is not so good. For the function $f(x)=x^x$ nomber $0$ is not in $dom(f)$, but there is a vertical tangent to the graph of $f$ in $(0,0).$ For $x\rightarrow0^+$ of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point on the curve where there is a vertical tangent line is necessarily a point where ${\large{\frac{dy}{dx}}}$ is undefined, so the only points where there *might* be a vertical tangent line are points on the curve where $x=3$.

But there are no points on the curve where $x=3$ since for $x=3$, the $\text{LHS}$ of the equation is equal to $0$ while the $\text{RHS}$ of the equation is equal to $81$.

Here's another way to understand it . . .

Since there are no points on the curve where $x=3$, the equation can be rewritten as
$$
y
=
\frac{x^4}{2(3-x)}
$$
valid for all $x$ in the domain $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}{\,\mid\,}x\ne 3\}$.

But for $x\in A$, ${\large{\frac{dy}{dx}}}$ exists, hence there are no points on the curve where there is a vertical tangent line.

Note that at $x=3$ there is a vertical  asymptote.

**A further note . . .**

If you have a curve given by an equation of the form $f(x,y)=0$, the points on the curve where there is a vertical tangent line are necessarily points where ${\large{\frac{dy}{dx}}}$ is undefined. But the converse is not true. As an example, for the curve $y=|x|$, at $x=0$, ${\large{\frac{dy}{dx}}}$ is undefined, but there are no points on the curve where there is a vertical tangent line.

In general, for a curve given by an equation of the form $f(x,y)=0$, the points on the curve where there is a vertical tangent line are the points on the curve where ${\large{\frac{dx}{dy}}}=0$.

Thus, the task of finding all such points can be accomplished as follows . . .

  $(1)\;\;$Differentiate the equation $f(x,y)=0\;$implicitly with respect to $y$.
  $(2)\;\;$Solve for ${\large{\frac{dx}{dy}}}$.

  $(3)\;\;$Solve the system
  $$
  \left\lbrace
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{dx}{dy}&=\,0\\[4pt]
  f(x,y)&=\,0\\[4pt]
  \end{align*}
  \right.
  $$

  $\qquad$for $x,y$.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem with the point.

This point just does not exist, which says that the needed tangent line does not exist.

Comment: I noticed that as well, this problem is kind of weird which is why I asked about it.

Comment: @CSS Jowoo  I think the right answer it's: The needed coordinate does not exist.